# Upgrading FCKeditor to CKeditor

Tags: php, ckeditor

I'm using `FCKeditor`  which is deprecated for years.

I need to upgrade to `CKeditor` (to at least 4.4+ however the `CKeditor`  documentation doesn't specify the minimum requirements for each version. What is the `PHP` version required etc?

Sadly `CKeditor` has no forum to ask general questions they refer all questions to stackoverflow.

Does anyone knows the minimum requirements?

Comment: @ADyson I'm aware of that but I'ts embedded in a PHP code...

Comment: yes but CKEditor itself doesn't communicate with the server, you must have  written code to do that, using HTTP requests. The version of PHP you're using is completely irrelevant to that. CKEditor neither knows nor cares what server language or version you're using. It doesn't even care if you ever save the data from the editor. It's all completely unrelated to the editor plugin.

Comment: @ADyson So if I want to upgrade to the latest version of CKeditor there shouldn't be any compatibility issues what so ever PHP or others?

Comment: It's of no consequence whatsoever. You may have to re-write a bit of your own code to be compatible in the sense of calling the CKEditor API properly, but it's nothing to do with versions of PHP. CKEditor doesn't use PHP, so it can't break it because of that. You could swap your PHP backend tomorrow for an ASP.NET one and CKEditor wouldn't even notice. You should be more concerned about browser versions perhaps, if they have any stipulations about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/guide/dev_savedata says:

> CKEditor helps you create content but it is the role of your website or application to deal with the data created in this way. Saving data is a server-side operation and you are free to implement the save functionality on your own, in any way you like. CKEditor is a pure JavaScript component and it does not offer anything more than JavaScript methods and events to access the data so that you could save it on the server.

As far as I can tell from this description, and from personal experience of the editor, it is an entirely client-side tool. It does not have any server-side component. It doesn't rely on or require PHP in any way at all. You can integrate it with any server-side language or framework to decide to, just by making HTTP requests to / from the server.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a specific instructions for migrating from FCKeditor  to CKeditor (version 4) ?

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head, sorry, you'd have to google it.

Answer (score 1):

The editor is a client side tool, I´m using the editor for years now, with any PHP-version... but PHP is not required at all. You can manage the CKEditor data with other server side languages also.
But there are differences between CKEditor 4 and CKEditor 5: Version 5 requires node.js , see the [documentation here](http://But%20there%20are%20differences%20between%20ckeditor%204%20and%20ckeditor%205)

Comment: Is there a guide how to upgrade from fckeditor to ckeditor?

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation](https://support.ckeditor.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002476505-How-do-I-switch-from-FCKeditor-)
And  there the instructions. ..